# Magento how to change action url of contact page

Tags: magento2, cms-block, contact-form, action

I add contact form in CMS page using this code -

```
   <form class="form contact"
  action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getFormAction()) ?>"
  id="contact-form"
  method="post"
  data-hasrequired="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('* Required Fields')) ?>"
  data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
<fieldset class="fieldset">
    <legend class="legend"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Write Us')) ?></span></legend><br />
    <div class="field note no-label"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Jot us a note and we’ll get back to you as quickly as possible.')) ?></div>
    <div class="field name required">
        <label class="label" for="name"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Name')) ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input name="name" id="name" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Name')) ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getPostValue('name') ?: $this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getUserName()) ?>" class="input-text" type="text" data-validate="{required:true}"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field email required">
        <label class="label" for="email"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Email')) ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input name="email" id="email" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Email')) ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getPostValue('email') ?: $this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getUserEmail()) ?>" class="input-text" type="email" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}"/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field telephone">
        <label class="label" for="telephone"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Phone Number')) ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <input name="telephone" id="telephone" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Phone Number')) ?>" value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getPostValue('telephone')) ?>" class="input-text" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="field comment required">
        <label class="label" for="comment"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('What’s on your mind?')) ?></span></label>
        <div class="control">
            <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('What’s on your mind?')) ?>" class="input-text" cols="5" rows="3" data-validate="{required:true}"><?= $block->escapeHtml($this->helper('Magento\Contact\Helper\Data')->getPostValue('comment')) ?></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?= $block->getChildHtml('form.additional.info') ?>
</fieldset>
<div class="actions-toolbar">
    <div class="primary">
        <input type="hidden" name="hideit" id="hideit" value="" />
        <button type="submit" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Submit')) ?>" class="action submit primary">
            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Submit')) ?></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

How to change action url of contact page.It transfer localhost/sanjeev/contacts/index/
I show contact form in footer section without action redirection other page.

Comment: Did you added the above html code to your cms page or you have called phtml in your cms page?

Comment: I call phtml file using this code -  {{block type="core/template" template="custom/yourform.phtml"}}

Comment: In Magento 1 or 2

Comment: I used Magento 2

Comment: If you are using magento2 then it will not work.

Comment: There is no more `core/template` in M2

Comment: This code work on magento 2 - {{block class="Magento\Contact\Block\ContactForm" name="contactForm" template="Magento_Contact::form.phtml"}}

Answer (score 0):

In the phtml file of the contact form, you need to change the form action.

You need to set the action URL as the current URL of the page, from where the contact form is being submitted.

To do so, just open the form.phtml file in your theme and change:

```
action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getFormAction()) ?>"
```

to:

```
action="<?= $this->getUrl('*/*/*', ['_current' => true, '_use_rewrite' => true]) ?>"
```

I hope it would help.

Comment: After add this code in action , contact form is not submitted

Comment: @Gagan, You have asked to change action URL, so the answer is correct. I think you want to change the URL where the user should redirect back after submitting the form. Please confirm?

Comment: yes, I want  to no redirection done after submitting form.

Comment: If you want to redirect back to the current page, I can help. Otherwise, you can submit the form using ajax.